# How to apply the distributive law on this logic statement?

Tags: logic

I am working through simplifying statements and am stuck on this example.

$[((\lnot p )\land(\lnot q))\lor((\lnot p)\land q)] \equiv [(\lnot p)\land ((\lnot q) \lor q))] $

Going from the left to the right, the author claimed to use the distributive law. Could someone please explain or write out how did they do that?

I tried distributing the $[((\lnot p )\land(\lnot q))$ into the $((\lnot p)\land q)$ but did not get anywhere.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may recognize the identity if we write it this way:
$$[\color{blue}{(\lnot p)\land} ((\lnot q) \lor q))] 
\equiv [(\color{blue}{(\lnot p )\land}(\lnot q))\lor(\color{blue}{(\lnot p)\land}q)]$$
Applied in the direction you have it, you might think of it as “factoring out” rather than “distributing over.”